# Traversing XML without conditions

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML structure I contains lot of nodes `<PName>`. What I need to do is Run an Xpath query match a condition extract some data. Run to the very next node test a condition then come back to the XPath query and continue the process

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PatientDetailsXML>
  <PList>
    <PName type="Patient">
      <properties>
        <Room bedType="Auto"/>
        <PName title="Joe Beom" PId="1234">
          <Details>
            <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Wallet"/>
            <classification classification="Humor" category="None"/>
            <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit"/>
          </Details>
        </PName>
      </properties>
      <childEvents>
      </childEvents>
    </PName>
    <PName type="Patient">
      <properties>
        <Room bedType="Auto"/>
        <PName title="John Bair" PId="1234">
          <Details>
            <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Found"/>
            <classification classification="Humor" category="None"/>
            <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit"/>
          </Details>
        </PName>
      </properties>
      <childEvents>
      </childEvents>
    </PName>
  </PList>
</PatientDetailsXML>
```

And this is my code:

```
var query = @"//PName[.//PName[Details/classification[@classification='paymenttype' and @category='Wallet']]]";   
foreach (XmlNode n in docs.SelectNodes(query))
{
    var titlelink = n.SelectSingleNode(".//PName/@title");
    var title = titlelink.Value;
    var bedlink = n.SelectSingleNode(".//Room/@bedType");
    var bed = bedlink.Value;
    // Here I want to run to the very next node <PName> and do 
    // some test's such as `classification='paymenttype' and 
    // @category='Wallet'`, if not true insert some data in XML
    // jump back to the XPATH node (where query was working at 
    // and continue the iteration). 
    // If it matches I fetch some data.
 }
```

I really have no idea how to navigate forcefully like this without a condition and ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a confusing question. Your title says without conditions. Your first paragraph says it must meet conditions and you end with "without a condition." In my opinion it's very difficult to write any code without any kind of branching code (conditions).

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expressions are not correct.
So change your C# code and its XPath expressions to

```
var query = @"//PName[Details/classification[@classification='paymenttype' and @category='Wallet']]"; 
// This query will select PName nodes with a condition
foreach (XmlNode n in docs.SelectNodes(query))
{
    var titlelink = n.SelectSingleNode("@title");
    var title = titlelink.Value;
    var bedlink = n.SelectSingleNode("../Room/@bedType");
    var bed = bedlink.Value;
}
```

This should get you closer to your goal.

---

If you want to retrieve nodes/values from another `PName` element, you can access it using XPath as well. For example, to get the `category` attribute value of the next `PName` element which has a `classification` attribute with the value "Food", you can use this XPath expression in the `foreach` loop:

```
var foodlink = n.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::PName/following-sibling::PName/properties/PName/Details/classification[@classification='Food']/@category");
var food = foodlink.Value;
```

Its output should be "Fruit".

Comment: Thanks but any idea how do i traverse xml e.g jumping to the next node

Comment: You traverse through the XML with the `foreach` loop. It iterates over all `PName` elements which satisfy the specified conditions.

Comment: Yes thats true but during the 1st iteration round in the for each loop i need to jump to the immediate next node test something and comeback to the foreach loop and continue

Comment: I extended my answer with a solution to access the next `PName` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement plist = doc.Descendants("PList").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> pName = plist.Elements("PName").ToList();

            var results = pName.Select(x => new {
                bedType = (string)x.Descendants("Room").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("bedType"),
                name = (string)x.Descendants("PName").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("title"),
                id = (string)x.Descendants("PName").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("PId"),
            }).ToList();


        }
    }
}
```